# Pass a String [] to an ArrayList <Integer>

Tags: java, string, arraylist, casting

I have a string of the form number, number, number, ... and I pass the string to int numbers and put them in a arraylist, but the loop iteration makes me less and do not know why

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> servs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] aux = result.split(";");
servs.clear();
for (int i =0; i< aux.length; i++)
{                       
       servs.add( Integer.parseInt(aux[i]) );                       
}
```

I explain better how @Luiggi Mendoza says:

for example, if result is the string: 3;4;7 and I check the size of aux I get 3 which is correct, but after I check the size for servs and tells me is 2 and the values 3 and 4

I added this code to debug

```
System.out.println("The String result is "+result);
System.out.println("The size of ArrayList is: " + servs.size());
System.out.println("The size of the Array is: " + aux.length);
```

And this is the results:

> The String result is: 3;5;7
>   The size of ArrayList is: 2
>
> The size of the Array is: 3

When I consult information arraylist always missing the last element
Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Try debugging, or at least provide example data to have better understanding of your specific issue (that I cannot find from the current code).

Comment: has the result variable a ; at the end?

Comment: Or show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've edited the post, @gaemaf the result variable doesn't have ; at the end, but the size of aux is 3

Comment: It would be better to also show the part of the code were you create `aux`.

Comment: Its working correctly: http://ideone.com/tglAt0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you checked the size and length, below is the code. You can see the results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = "3;4;7";
    ArrayList<Integer> servs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] aux = result.split(";");
    for (int i =0; i< aux.length; i++)
    {                       
           servs.add( Integer.parseInt(aux[i]) );                       
    }
    System.out.println("The ArrayList Items "+ servs);
    System.out.println("The size of ArrayList is: " + servs.size());
    System.out.println("The size of the Array is: " + aux.length);
}
```

and the result

```
The ArrayList Items [3, 4, 7]
The size of ArrayList is: 3
The size of the Array is: 3
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/R6JyNU)